# meaning of "make sense"

Tags: phrase-meaning, ambiguity

The following sentence is ambiguous. But does it make sense? Someone insists that ambiguous sentences don't make sense. Maybe "make sense" has a special meaning I am not aware of?

> John saw the girl with a pair of binoculars.

Comment: No pun intended, but your cited text ***makes two senses*** - except idiomatically that's not valid, so I'd have to say something like ***carries** two senses [simultaneously]*.

Comment: "Ambiguous" does not mean "doesn't make sense". Is that the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Ambiguous sentences can mean more than one thing.  So such sentences will make sense, but will it make the specific sense you intend?

Context will often be the "tiebreaker" and prevent problems.  When ambiguous sentences are taken out of context, that might confuse someone - but it's not the original sentence's fault.

> John saw the girl with a pair of binoculars.

Did John see a girl with binoculars, or use the binoculars to see the girl?

If we were talking about John earlier and the listener/reader can infer John doesn't have binoculars, then there is no ambiguity because context resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing ambiguity:

"John saw the girl with a pair of binoculars." can mean:

1. He used binoculars to see her.
2. He saw the girl who had the binoculars. [in her hands, around her neck]

New sentences:

1. John used binoculars to see the girl.
2. John saw the girl who was holding or using or carrying binoculars.

Comment: I might very well say that I saw someone _through_ binoculars or a telescope.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sure, and that would be another way to  say 1).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  If a sentence is ambiguous, does it still make sense?

Comment: @Apollyon - it makes two kinds of sense, which is what ambiguous means.